# Добавить ReactJS в проект

Tags: html, jquery, css, reactjs

Подскажите начинающему: есть сверстанная страничка со всякими мультиселектами, поиском по ней и так далее. Хочу переписать всё jQuery на React, соответственно и переверстать некоторые компоненты и части проекта. Подскажите, как добавить React в проект. Json файл создан, на локальном запускал, т.е. npm зависимости добавил, а вот как собственно "внедрить" React нигде не нашел. Если не трудно, подскажите..

Comment: Судя по вашему вопросу, мне кажется, что вы не совсем понимаете, что такое ReactJs.   
Вы работали вообще с ним? Вы использовали `create-react-app` ?

Comment: нет, я понимаю, что такое React. я работал с ним и вот я сделал на нём отдельно проект с мультиселектом, теперь гадаю как добавить со всеми зависимостями в проект, не пересоздавать новые, а добавить в уже сверстанный макет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на Ваш вопрос можно найти на официальной странице библиотеки:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html

Чтобы установить React через npm, Вам следует ввести следующую команду:

```
npm install --save react react-dom
```

После чего библиотека будет добавлена в файл зависимостей Вашего проекта. Теперь Вы можете подключать и использовать её.

Пример использования, опять же, указан на странице, приведенной выше:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: нужно ли мне добавлять сборщик типа Gulp или менеджеры пакетов Bower , например, или могу обойтись?

Comment: Всё зависит от задач, которые Вы преследуете. Конечно, Вы можете обойтись без Gulp. Вы можете писать код, используя React, установив и подключив необходимые для этой библиотеки модули, которые указаны в моем ответе. 

Если Вы хотите использовать JSX в своем коде, Вам придется подключить компилятор, который будет переводить Ваш JSX-код в JavaScript-код, который понимается React'ом. Используйте Babel для этого. Опять же, об установке всё написано на официальном сайте:
http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation

Можете просто скачать babel и подключить его в html как скрипт. Всё заработает.

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ!